# Transformation from spherical to cylindrical coordinates

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

I have a coordinate on the surface of a sphere i.e latitude and longitude(two dimensions). I need to transform into a 2-D cylindrical coordinate frame i.e. r and the azimuth angle theta. Is there a transformation matrix between the two without converting to Cartesian in between ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point $(r, \theta, \phi)$ in spherical coordinates, can be represented as $(\rho, \varphi, z) = (r\cos\theta, \phi, r\sin\theta)$ in cylindrical coordinates. In this convention $\theta$ represents the latitude, and $\phi$ the longitude

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am a bit confused. I do not have a "r" in my case as I only have 2D coordinates. Will this still work by taking r to be 1 ?

Comment: @gansub In the surface of a sphere $r$ is constant (the radius of the sphere)

Comment: so in my case "r" = 1 will be correct am I right ?

Comment: @gansub Kind of difficult to say without further context, but you can alway scale your problem. So yes, you can use $r=1$

Comment: final question before accepting your answer. So in my case latitude and longitude is nothing but phi and r cos theta in the cylindrical coordinate system right ? If you can edit your answer with a mapping that would be helpful.